# REGEX: excluding a string from a pattern that is already excluding particular characters

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to write a regular expression to use to validate a url path. We orginally had the pattern: [^#\?:]+ which would grab everything up until the first ?, : or # from the path.

We now want to also exclude the string 'index.cfm'.

I can't work out how to include this though. I've had a look at lookarounds but I can't seem to work out how to use it in conjunction with the pattern we already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Here's an edited solution according to your comment.

```
^.*?(?=[#?:]|index\.cfm|$)
```

Here's a demo using the site you mentioned: http://regexr.com?31rk9.

Comment: I used http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ to check that and it selected the 'ndex.cfm/.....' up to the first question mark.   I want to select everything up until the first ? # : or 'index.cfm'

Comment: Sure!  It says, "The shortest substring, starting from the beginning of the string (``^``), that is immediately followed (``(?=...)``) by [1] one of the characters in ``#?:``, [2] the string 'index.cfm', or [3] the end of the string."  The last part is important.  It's what makes the regex capture _everything it can_, **unless** one of the two preceding conditions (the ``#?:`` characters, or "index.cfm") are encountered.

Comment: Ah thanks! must have been the last bit that I was missing earlier :D

Answer (score 0):

should work for you
`^(?P<url>[^#?:](?!index\.cfm))+`